# WordPressダッシュボードにアクセスできません

Tags: wordpress

### 前提・実現したいこと

初めて WordPress を始めようとしている初心者です。

使っているのドメインは Xdomain の有料一年契約のドメインで、 Xdomain の無料サーバーを利用しています。

Xdomain さんの管理パネル->インストール済み WordPress 一覧->ダッシュボードへ
というところからダッシュボードにアクセスしようとしているのですが、下記のようにエラーが起きて入れない状況です。

自分のパソコンの個人的にダウンロードした FFFTP というソフトからはアクセスでき、何のファイルがあるのかなどは確認できます。
いろいろダウンロードされていて正しくインストールされているっポイです。

---

### 発生している問題

WordPress ダッシュボードにアクセスできません

ダッシュボードにアクセスしようとすると以下の様になります。

> このページを表示できません
>
> #### 対処方法
>
> - Web アドレスが正しいことを確認してください: [http://---自分のURL---.com](http://---%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AEURL---.com)
> - Bing で "[http://---自分のURL---.com](http://---%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AEURL---.com)" を検索してください
>
> ページを最新の情報に更新
>
> #### Details
>
> The DNS name does not exist.
>   Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

URL には [http://---自分のURL---.com/wp-admin/](http://---%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AEURL---.com/wp-admin/) が入力されています。

---

### 試したこと

- `WP_DEBUG` のfalse を true にした

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

- Explore のキャッシュの削除
- Explore のパスワードのリセット
- インストールした WordPress の初期化、アンインストール、再設置

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/144369

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10196015450

Answer (score 0):

Xdomainのサポートに聞くべき内容です。
あとExploreではなくIEまたはInternet Explorerと記載したほうが良いです。

Answer (score 0):

こちらもう解決済みですか？
私も試してみましたが、URLはhttp://---自分のURL---.com/wp-admin/で問題なさそうです。